# Why does SonarQube find this issue (<static initializer for >() uses a Side Effect Constructor) with case and object class files?

Tags: scala, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When running a SonarQube scan all `case class` and `object` scala files are flagged with a weird issue:
`Method com.org.package.ExampleCaseClass$.<static initializer for >() uses a Side Effect Constructor`

If I convert it to a normal class the issue goes away oddly enough. What is it that is different for the case classes/objects?

Decompiling the Scala into Java shows that there does exist a static block:

```
   public static final ExampleCaseClass$ MODULE$;

   static {
      new ExampleCaseClass$();
   }
```

Example case class with the issue:

```
case class ExampleCaseClass(var1: String,
                       var2: String,
                       var3: String,
                       var4: String,
                       var5: String,
                       var6: String,
                       var7: String,
                       var8: String)
```

Sonar expands on the issue saying:

- This method creates an object but does not assign this object to any variable or field. This implies that the class operates through side effects in the constructor, which is a bad pattern to use, as it adds unnecessary coupling. Consider pulling the side effect out of the constructor, into a separate method, or into the calling method.

However, considering this class just takes strings in the constructor I'm not sure what the side effect could be. Is this a false positive?

Comment: `var1: String` is declared twice in the constructor!

Comment: Sorry, that was just an artifact of renaming all the fields to a generic name for StackOverflow.

Comment: in this case it's hard to receive a good advice for such a sneaky issue without the actual code :P

Answer (score 2):

Eventually it was decided to mark the Sonar issue as a false positive and move on about our lives.